# Cut desired HTML part from DOM object

Tags: html, css, parsing, simple-html-dom

I am trying to get one specific css class from my DOM object. I use simplehtmldom library.

1) The library

[simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net)

2) Because my localhost doesnt support fopen for some reason, I use the CURL library to get the HTML, source:

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_faq.htm

3) Now, my script looks like this. It gives me source of HTML from the website which I desire.

```
<?php
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://hokejbal.cz/1-liga/tabulky/");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    print $result;

    str_get_dom;
    $ret = $html->find('.standings tablesort tablesorter tablesorter-default');
?>
```

4) Now, I want to get just a part of the website. Exactly this table:

```
<table class="standings tablesort tablesorter tablesorter-default">
```

I found it in Google Chrome webmaster tools

Unfortunately, when I run the script, I get whole HTML page, not just the desired part. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector would be `'.standings.tablesort.tablesorter.tablesorter-default'`

Update: Try the below code.

```
<?php
    $html = file_get_html('http://hokejbal.cz/1-liga/tabulky/');  
    $ret = $html->find('table.standings', 0);
    print $ret;
?>
```

Comment: that or just give it some unique ID and/or Class `class='table-01 ...`

Comment: Nope, it doesnt work, 
@Miro  I cant give it unique class
 because I am not owner of the source.

Comment: Are there other tables in the source with the `standings` class? I not, try `'table.standings'`

Comment: @MaartenvanTjonger nah it doesnt help as well. Maybe take a look at the website? THere are two tables with same class, isnt this the problem?
http://hokejbal.cz/1-liga/tabulky/

Comment: Try using `$html->find('table.standings', 0);` to get the first one.

Comment: @MaartenvanTjonger nah, nothing at all. Stil lloading whole HTML instead of just the table

Comment: @MaartenvanTjonger Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function str_get_html() in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\index.php:22 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\index.php on line 22

Comment: Okay, this is some step forward. Now I get the first table from the website. But Id like the second one. Is there some way how to get just the second one?  I had also to set offset = 0 at simplehtmldom library on line 75 @MaartenvanTjonger

Comment: Use `$html->find('table.standings', 1);` to get the second table.